# How to install subversion 1.6.x on SLE11?

Tags: software-installation, subversion, zypper

I need specific version of subversion 1.6.x on my SLE11 (SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64)) but I do not know how to install it.

If I follow the instructions on http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=devel:tools:scm:svn&package=subversion I get subversion 1.7.x installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best ways is to get source code from [subversion official site](http://subversion.apache.org) and compile it manually.

In my own experience, If you compile it without berkeley db, there would be no problem with other dependencies. To do so, you should pass `--without-berkeley-db` option to `./configure` command.